# What's the difference between Coldfusion Developer Edition and Enterprise Edition?

Tags: coldfusion, webserver, dreamweaver

I'm trying to test Coldfusion for learning purposes, but I really don't know what is the aditional features that the non-free Enterprise Edition add to the free Developer Edition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Legally, Enterprise is for public consumption, and Dev is not.

Practically, this means that the Dev edition (which is the same as the Eval edition after the 30? days) is limited to localhost + 1 IP address.  That is, it can serve files to localhost and 1 external IP.  This IP can only be reset by restarting the service.

Otherwise, your dev install will mimic an ent install completely.

Comment: I believe Developer edition can be access by 2 remote IP's + localhost. Everything you really need can be found here --> 
http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/editions/

Comment: It might be two.  I was doing this from memory.  But the idea gets across, and 2 IPs probably isn't enough for a production server.  :-)

Comment: @BenDoom Can we deploy our production website with this DEVELOPER edition ?

Comment: @Mani7TAM This is from the Adobe license agreement for CF2021
"3.3.1 Developer Edition Software. Adobe grants Licensee a license to install and use the Developer Edition Software on one Computer workstation. Licensee must separately obtain the right to install or use the Software as Developer Edition Software on more than one workstation. Licensee’s license to the Developer Edition Software is limited to use in Licensee’s technical environment strictly for testing and development purposes and not for staging or live or standby production purposes."

Answer (score 8):

The developer edition of Adobe ColdFusion Server is limited by IP addresses - only the localhost and 1 other IP address can access the server. Any more, and it will throw license exceptions.

Also, printable items such as documents created with cfdocument and cfpresentation are watermarked with a gigantic diagonal banner over each page.

Otherwise, the dev and enterprise editions both have all the features enabled, including advanced debugging and server monitoring, PDF & FlashPaper generation, advanced gateways, 64 bit CPU support and full database drivers including Oracle - the works.

The Trial edition of ColdFusion is the same as enterprise for 30 days, but then drops to be the developer edition after 30 days - once the license has expired. Do make sure you remember to get your serial number in if you put this on production :)

For reference, see [Adobe ColdFusion Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/editions/).

Comment: Good point about the document watermarks.  I'd forgotten that.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a pain if the applications you're running produce a lot of PDFs. Then again, that's the whole point of the license, I suppose ... otherwise we'd simply steer requests to a developer edition and generate PDFs for free.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the line: "Used for delivering multiple websites and applications on one or more servers"

The Enterprise Edition allows for deployment for commercial purposes.

The Development Edition allows you to develop locally, but not deploy.  The deployment requires Enterprise or Standard editions, or purchasing a hosting solution which handles the licensing for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go.](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/editions/)

Edit: Scroll to bottom for Dev v. Ent. discussion.

Comment: That only compares Standard <-> Enterprise+Dev (which have the same features), but doesn't tell you how Enterprise differs from Developer edition.  It's a licensing difference, not a technical difference.

Comment: Did you read the whole thing or just neg me?

ColdFusion 8 Developer is a free, fully functional version of ColdFusion for local development of applications that will be deployed on either Standard or Enterprise servers. In addition to localhost, applications running on a Developer Edition server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer 
Stack Overflow Help Center
"Provide context for links"

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."