# ColdFusion 8 Diffie-Hellman Encryption

Tags: java, encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, diffie-hellman

I am integrating with a 3rd party that requires I use the Diffie-Hellman encryption algorithm. The CF docs [indicate that this is a supported algorithm](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_01.html).

When I attempt to call `Encrypt()` with either "Diffie-Hellman" or "DH" I get the error message: "The Diffie-Hellman algorithm is not supported by the Security Provider you have chosen."

Is it possible to configure CF to use a different Security Provider that would include DH? Or, Is it possible to use java objects directly to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The Diffie-Hellman algorithm is only supported by Enterprise edition.
*(this is documented in the page you linked to, but it's not entirely clear)*

If you only have Standard edition then you'll need to find an [existing Java implementation](http://www.google.com/search?q=Diffie-Hellman%20java) you can use with `createObject('java','...')`, or maybe reimplement one with pure CFML.

If you do the latter, it would be great to share the code on [riaforge](http://riaforge.org/)/[github](http://github.com/)/wherever, so other CFML users can benefit.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745921/whats-the-difference-between-coldfusion-developer-edition-and-enterprise-edition it seems that the developer edition is a limited simultaneous connection version of the enterprise edition.  If that is in fact the case, then DH should work, but what I'm getting at is that i don't think DH is actually implemented despite what the docs say. So, I think i will need a work around.

Comment: Howie, developer edition is only useful for _development_. Not only that, but it violates the terms of service to use it for production usage (even if the access limitations are acceptable for your production environment). Henry, don't confuse Developer edition with Standard edition. The feature should be accessible using **Developer Edition** (which Howie mentioned), for testing/proof-of-concept, but will not be at all accessible in Standard Edition. At any rate, Peter is correct about your options.

Comment: We use enterprise on our production servers but I need to be able to test this functionality (if it exists) in the developer edition. If this cannot be done with built in CF functions, Can you recommend a specific Java implementation to use instead?