# Coldfusion Developer Edition legal for development team members?

Tags: coldfusion, licensing

I know that Coldfusion developer edition is technically similar to its enterprise edition with limited features but from legal perspective, is it legal to use developer edition within development team of a company for the development of a commercial application?

Please note, I've already read Coldfusion EULA and many replies to questions where people said developer edition is freely available. Now, my doubt is: Isn't there any "per user license" kind of thing for coldfusion development team members in an IT company as in case of visual studio and other softwares? because if we don't need any license within development team then a team of 10 or 1000 members must be able to develop applications for cost of just 1 license of enterprise edition for production server, which shouldn't be possible AFAIK.

Comment: A coupla people have flag this for closing as "off topic", however that's not correct in my reading of the FAQ as "on topic" covers questions about the tools one developer with, and that would cover licensing of said tools. It's a lazy question (so down vote it, sure), but it's not off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me about 30sec to google the [ColdFusion EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eula/server/) which has all these details in it.

Bottom line is the developer edition licence works as follows:

> ColdFusion 10 Developer Edition is a free, fully functional version of
>   ColdFusion for local host development of applications that will be
>   deployed on either standard or enterprise servers and can be
>   simultaneously accessed from two remote IP addresses.

[From the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html).

How come you didn't just google this stuff? Wouldn't that have been easier than posting a question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Well thanks for your effort. I did google this but got confused with word localhost as it can be an individual PC or developer machine within an organization. And, I'm not sure how licensing works for Development/QA/UAT team within an organization so looking for the clarification.

Comment: Moreover, i know that there's a similar question on stackoverflow.com [What's the difference between Coldfusion Developer Edition and Enterprise Edition?](
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745921/whats-the-difference-between-coldfusion-developer-edition-) but again nothing has been mentioned there about licensing within an organization. I didn't ask there because that's a very old question and i thought no one would notice my question there. So, i'm seeking help from people who have knowledge of licensing in development team within an organization.

Comment: There's only one interpretation of "localhost" that I'm aware of (and I'll not be so patronising as to explain that, as I'm sure you know).  The dev licence permits development on a person sitting on that machine, basically, and one other person *not* on that machine. If you want to have a shared development server, then you need a full licence. If you want a QA/UAT server, then you also need a full licence. This is all in the licence doc.

Comment: It is worth noting that as of CF9 (indicated in section 3.1.3) and in CF10 (indicated in section 3.2.1) if you own a license of standard or enterprise, you may install it again for development purposes. This is not considered the "developer edition" and is a full IP UN-restricted version. http://blog.terrenceryan.com/coldfusion-9-testing-staging-and-development-changes-to-eula/ and http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/adobe_coldfusion_mutli_20120302_1201.pdf

Comment: see also, the coldfusion blog `Testing, staging and development still free` http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-eula

Comment: Aah... I remember the bit about being allowed to have a cold stand-by server now (licensed via its equivalent live server), but forgot about that. Cheers for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not require a license to run Developer edition.

Comment: Thanks. But, i have a doubt. Coldfusion developer edition is like visual studio express edition and express edition is not allowed to use within development team. Indeed we need standard or professional edition for development. So, are you sure developer edition can be used for development in a company? Because this way a team of 10 or 1000 developers would need just 1 license of coldfusion for production environment and i think that shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: For Pete's sake. YES. We are sure. I've been doing this for over a decade. Don't ask a question and then contradict the answer if you get confused by words like "localhost", cannot understand an EULA, and can't even apply *common sense* to work out that something called "developer edition" is intended for developers. You just make yourself look dim.

Comment: It's also useful to consider that a licence *restricts things*. If a licence doesn't expressly restrict something, then it's not a restriction of the licence.

Comment: Re: *visual studio express edition .. is not allowed to use within development team* No, the [**express** version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Express) [is free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420710/can-i-produce-commercial-code-with-visual-studio-express-editions). Sounds like you are confusing it with one of the full fledged [visual studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) editions (professional, premimum, ...) which *do* have restrictions.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma is justified in skepticism about 1000 developers on one production license. From CF2021 license https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/en/legal/licenses-terms/pdf/Adobe_ColdFusion2021-en_US-20201111.pdf "This Section 3.3 applies only if Licensee has obtained a valid license for ... Production Software. 3.3.1 Developer Edition Software. Adobe grants Licensee a license to install and use the Developer Edition Software on one Computer workstation. Licensee must separately obtain the right to install or use the Software as Developer Edition Software on more than one workstation."